# Use an old driver (for OSX 10.3) in a new mac (OSX 10.8/9)

Tags: macos, printing, driver, panther

I have a printer (Sansung ML-1250) that has [driver for OSX 10.3](http://www.samsung.com/it/support/model/ML-1250W/XET-downloads?downloadName=DR) but now I have a new mac with OSX 10.9 and I'm not sure how to handle it.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

You are in luck. Your printer is supported by the Gutenprint open source printer drivers.

http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php

Install these and you should be OK. You may find not all functions of the printer are supported but usually with Gutenprint they come close.

Answer (score 0):

The OS X Printer driver framework was heavily overhauled around the time of 10.6 so, to be frank, there's not a hope in hell that it'll work. You'll need to replace your printer with something newer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a Macbook which you can set back to 10.3 there's no way you can use it anymore. 
Old printers are a pain for new software, as they will always remain slower than the applications (in the future) will ever be.

Sorry but no, you have either have a 2nd machine which you can set back to 10.3 or you have to get a newer printer.